# Remove Lines from MapboxGL map

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a React function like the following. When a button is clicked, this function places a square on a map of the world at the specified coordinates (see code). However, I want to be able to press a different button and have the square removed. How can I do this? Is there a way to delete things from MapboxGL maps? If so, what function can I use?

The square is rendered using a function from MapboxGL and the web app is made using React JS.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {

    if(props.show) {
      console.log(props);
      var northEast = [131.308594, 46.195042];
      var southEast = [117.597656, 8.233237];
      var southWest = [79.101563, 32.842674];
      var northWest = [86.847656, 44.715514];

      // Add bounding box to the map
      // Defines bounding box
      globalMap.addSource('newroute', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [
                    northEast, southEast, southWest, northWest, northEast
                ]
            }
        }
      });

      // Draws bounding box
      globalMap.addLayer({
        'id': 'newroute',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'newroute',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#ff0000',
            'line-width': 5
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox-GL has a [remove layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#removelayer) method.

```js
// If a layer with ID 'target-layer' exists, remove it.
if (map.getLayer('target-layer')) map.removeLayer('target-layer');
```

Another way to approach the issue is to keep the old layer, and update the data of the source with the new data (if your use-case allows for it).

"Remove layer" by setting the data of the source to an empty dataset:

```js
map.getSource('target-source').setData({ type: "FeatureCollection", features: [] });
```

You can then set the data to a populated GeoJSON object if and when you have new data...